# ratio_to_report in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a a table that looks like

```
SELECT Client, Cost, Tier from table_x

Client|Cost|Tier|
abc   | 10 | 2  |
def   | 9  | 1  |
ghk   | 1  | 1  |
abc   | 20 | 1  |
```

What I am looking to work out is the %occupation by spend of each tier i.e. out of the total spend in Tier one, what % does the client occupy each tier.

In this instance ABC has the highest tier one spend, so I want to work out out of  the total spend in this tier, what % does ABC's make up.

I reason `RATIO TO REPORT (Spend) OVER (PARTITION BY Cost, Tier)` to work this out?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And edit your question with the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       (cost / sum(cost) over ()) as tier_1_ratio_for_client
from t
where tier = 1;
```